# Enviado String em pagina PHP para outra Pagina HTML

Tags: php

Ola,

Comecei a programar em PHP esses dias e não estou conseguindo retornar uma String de uma pagina PHP que roda em BackEnd para uma pagina PHP com HTML e apresentar essa String

Editado: Vou explicar o processo como um todo para melhora o Entendimento, tenho uma pagina inicial PHP que contem apenas HTML que carrega o arquivo TXT para leitura nessa segunda pagina PHP com o código abaixo. Preciso retornar para uma pagina php com HTML e mostrar para o Usuario

```
$uploaddir = 'tempArq/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['Arquivo']['name'];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Arquivo Enviado<br/>";
    $retorno;
    $ponteiro = fopen($uploadfile, "r");
    $arr = array();
    while (!feof($ponteiro)) {
        $linha = fgets($ponteiro, 4096);
        array_push($arr, $linha);
        if (strlen($linha) >= 10){
        $resultado = ConsultaWebserices($linha);
        $retorno = "TiqueteID : $linha : Status" + $resultado;
    }else {
        echo "Tiquete ID $linha Invalido <br/>";
    }
}
fclose($ponteiro);
unlink($uploadfile);
```

Preciso pegar o Valor $retorno e chamar uma pagina PHP com HTML e apresentar esse valor em um Table. 
Como eu faço essa chamada da outra pagina e recebo o valor do $retorno na outra pagina para Apresentar.

Comment: Ao que parece isso é uma função que retorna algo, você poderia transformar isso em uma função e somente dar um return, ou também se não for isso que quer e quiser transitar com os valores pelas páginas use cookie http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: a concatenação no php é um ponto (.) Então seria `$retorno = "TiqueteID : $linha : Status ".$resultado;`

Comment: Esse seu `if` já funciona?

Comment: Você pode fazer na própria pagina desse processamento ou enviar para outra pagina

Comment: Sim o If Funciona, e já modifiquei a concatenação @adventistaam não entendi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aproveitando o bloco que você informou dá para fazer de duas formas

```
    $uploaddir = 'tempArq/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['Arquivo']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Arquivo Enviado<br/>";
        $retorno;
        $ponteiro = fopen($uploadfile, "r");
        $arr = array();
        while (!feof($ponteiro)) {
            $linha = fgets($ponteiro, 4096);
            array_push($arr, $linha);
            if (strlen($linha) >= 10){
            $resultado = ConsultaWebserices($linha);
            $retorno = "TiqueteID : $linha : Status" + $resultado;
        }else {
            echo "Tiquete ID $linha Invalido <br/>";
        }
    }
    fclose($ponteiro);
    unlink($uploadfile);
```

> **1ª Forma**

```
$uploaddir = 'tempArq/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['Arquivo']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Arquivo Enviado<br/>";
        $retorno;
        $ponteiro = fopen($uploadfile, "r");
        $arr = array();
        $retorno = ""; 
        while (!feof($ponteiro)) {
            $linha = fgets($ponteiro, 4096);
            array_push($arr, $linha);
            if (strlen($linha) >= 10){
               $resultado = ConsultaWebserices($linha);
               $retorno .= "TiqueteID : $linha : Status" . $resultado."\n";
            }else {
               echo "Tiquete ID $linha Invalido <br/>";
            }
       }

    //mostrando o retorno na mesma página do processamento do arquivo:
    echo $retorno;
  }
    fclose($ponteiro);
    unlink($uploadfile);
```

> **2ª Forma usando o header**

```
    $uploaddir = 'tempArq/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['Arquivo']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Arquivo Enviado<br/>";
        $retorno;
        $ponteiro = fopen($uploadfile, "r");
        $arr = array();
        $retorno = ""; 
        while (!feof($ponteiro)) {
            $linha = fgets($ponteiro, 4096);
            array_push($arr, $linha);
            if (strlen($linha) >= 10){
               $resultado = ConsultaWebserices($linha);
               $retorno .= "TiqueteID : $linha : Status" . $resultado."\n";
            }else {
               echo "Tiquete ID $linha Invalido <br/>";
            }
       }


  }
    fclose($ponteiro);
    unlink($uploadfile);
   //enviando o valor para outra página
   header ("location: suapagina.php?retorno=".$retorno);
```

Aí na outra página você recebe

```
$retorno = $_GET['retorno'];
echo $retorno
```

Comment: eu verifiquei, mas o header ("location: suapagina.php?retorno=".$retorno); não sobe a outra pagina e o primeiro exemplo não esquece na tela. O header ("location: suapagina.php?retorno=".$retorno); na "suapagina.php" eu coloco o caminho interno da pagina, porque meus arquivos estão separados por pacotes e mesmo mapeando isso não abre 
Exemplo "header ("location: APP\VIEWS\PGVIEW\closedPreBaixa.php?retorno=".$retorno);"

Comment: Como assim: ` o primeiro exemplo não esquece na tela`? E `não sobe a outra`?

Comment: Aí depende de está o arquivo que ler o seu arquivo text

Comment: Você está usando algum framework?

Comment: Preciso de o retorno abra uma outra pagina em php com o $retorno impresso nessa pagina a complicação que apos a execução desse código.    
   //enviando o valor para outra página
   header ("location: suapagina.php?retorno=".$retorno)
Não abre a minha pagina.

Comment: Dá alguma mensagem? Por que você não armazena o $retorno em vetor? pelo header ele encontra a proxima pagina?

Comment: Não aparece Nenhuma Msg, apenas a pagina não abre fica uma pagina em banco não carrega a pagina necessária, se ele abrir a pagina já resolve

Comment: Tem como você colocar seu codigo no github para gente analisar?

Answer (score 1):

Inclui o arquivo em sua página e chama a variável ou oque seja dele, ex o placeholder o input  text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

include 'seuarquivo.php';
//Suponde que a variável $texto exista no 'seuarquivo.php'
    echo "<input type='text' name='text' placeholder='$texto'>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dessa forma se ele ter htmls no outro arquivo o mesmo será mostrado nessa página onde ele incluir

Comment: Acho que eu não detalhei um pouco superficialmente, Eu tenho uma pagina inicial PHP HTML que carrega o um arquivo TXT e chama essa pagina que esta colada no inicio, após a execução dessa pagina eu quero pegar o resultado e abrir uma terceira pagina com o retorno.